# When studying the dihedral group of a square, do we consider only vertices or the whole points which the square covers?

Tags: symmetry

When studying the dihedral group of a square, do we consider only vertices or the whole points which the square covers? Because the vertices of square also gives the same symmetries.

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question.  The set of vertices of the square has the same symmetries as the whole set of points of the square.  Or perhaps I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Absolutely but which set do we consider in dihedral group of order 8

Answer (score 0):

When studying the symmetry groups of a whole geometric object, the symmetry of all points of that object is considered.

Take e.g. a square that contains a non-symmetric pattern on its surface: it has a different symmetry group than a square: its symmetry group is the identity group.

Comment: Can you elaborate please